# I try to make a Unity Curved Shader with shadow Effect?

Tags: unity, shaders, unityscript

I try to make a curved shader with shadow effect I got a existing curved shader in github and it has no shadow effect i try to modify it but i couldn't find any appropriate solution.

The shaderor helping script link: https://gist.github.com/g0ody/5550039

**Curved.shader:**

Shader "Platogo/Curved" {
    Properties {
    _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _QOffset ("Offset", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
    _Dist ("Distance", Float) = 100.0
  }
    SubShader {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        Pass
        {
            Lighting Off

```
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _QOffset;
        float _Dist;
        uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;

        struct v2f {
    float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        v2f vert (appdata_base v)
        {
    v2f o;
    float4 vPos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MV, v.vertex);
    float zOff = vPos.z/_Dist;
    vPos += _QOffset*zOff*zOff;
    o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_P, vPos);
    o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
    return o;
        }

        half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
        {
          return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
FallBack "Mobil/Unlit"
```

}

**CurvedAlpha.shader**

Shader "Platogo/CurvedAlpha" {
  Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
        _QOffset ("Offset", Vector) = (0,0,0,0)
        _Dist ("Distance", Float) = 100.0
        _Alpha ("Alpha", Range(0.0,1.0)) = 1.0
    }
    SubShader {
        Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
        LOD 100

```
    ZWrite On
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha 

    Pass
    {
        Lighting Off

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _QOffset;
        float _Dist;
        float _Alpha;
        uniform float4 _MainTex_ST;

        struct v2f {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        v2f vert (appdata_base v)
        {
            v2f o;
            float4 vPos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_MV, v.vertex);
            float zOff = vPos.z/_Dist;
            vPos += _QOffset*zOff*zOff;
            o.pos = mul (UNITY_MATRIX_P, vPos);
            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
            return o;
        }

        half4 frag (v2f i) : COLOR
        {
            return tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * float4(1,1,1,_Alpha);
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

FallBack "Platogo/Unlit Texture Alpha"
}

[image: Sample of what i need]

Comment: https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/animal-crossing-curved-world-shader/